# Independent hanging indent subject to word length under "Description"

Tags: indentation, description

[image]

When using description, how can I adjust particular indent by given wordlength for every `description`?

Or to say, how can I get command such as `\settowidth`, `\hangindent` and `\mbox` to work under `description`?

【CODE】

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,enumitem}

\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}


\item [Short head] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.

\item [Head]Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.

\begin{spacing}{2}

\item [Long long long long head] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,    consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabiturdictum gravida mauris.  Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.

\end{spacing}

\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option, as long as you're willing to use `\item[<description>]{text}` (I added `\raggedright` to the last item text just to prevent bad inter-word spacing in the narrow space):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,enumitem}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{linegoal}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\LetLtxMacro\olditem\item
\AtBeginEnvironment{description}{
\renewcommand\item[2][]{
  \olditem[%
    {\begin{varwidth}[t]{\textwidth}#1\end{varwidth}}]%
    \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linegoal}#2\end{varwidth}%
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[leftmargin=0pt]
\item[Short head]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.}

\item[Head]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.}

\begin{spacing}{2}

\item[Long long long long head]{\raggedright Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,    consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabiturdictum gravida mauris.  Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.}

\end{spacing}

\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't really like this solution for two reasons: since the description is placed in an argument, verbatim material will be problematic and, most importantly, since descriptions are inside a box, they won't admit page breaks

Comment: @Howard You're welcome! I updated my answer to make sure thet the redefinition of `\item` affects only `description`. I thanks you for accepting the answer, but  (just as a suggestion), perhaps you would wait a little longer in case a better answer pops-up? I mean an answer lifting the restriction to enclose the description in braces?